# Joining Two Woocommerce Tables

Tags: mysql, join, woocommerce

I am trying to join two standard woocommerce tables and get the results.
My ultimate goal being to get out the zone_name based off a location_code.

My current query is as follows but with no results:

```
<?php
function prntPage() {
    global $wpdb;

    // The SQL query
    $results =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT location_code, zone_id, zone_name ".
                "FROM {$wpdb->prefix} woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
                "JOIN {$wpdb->prefix} woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
                "ON (woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id)");

    // Loop though rows data
    foreach( $results as $row ){
       echo $row ."<br>";
    }
}
prntPage();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you not enabled error reporting? this should have given you an error

`{$wpdb->prefix}`has to be direct in front of the table names at any time

```
$results =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT location_code, zone_id, zone_name ".
                "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations ".
                "JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones ".
                "ON ({$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_shipping_zones.zone_id)");
```

but it seems more logical

`{$wpdb->prefix}`has to be direct in front of the table names at any time

```
$results =  $wpdb-> get_results("SELECT location_code, zone_id, zone_name ".
                "FROM {$wpdb->prefix}shipping_zone_locations ".
                "JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}shipping_zones ".
                "ON ({$wpdb->prefix}shipping_zone_locations.zone_id = {$wpdb->prefix}shipping_zones.zone_id)");
```

Because woocommerce_ is already your prefix.

Comment: Still not pulling in anything or at least I can't echo out the $results to anything.

Comment: run the quey in phpmyadmin or workbench istead of {$wpdb->prefix} pu your actual prox and see if you get results

Comment: also you can echo results, it shpuld be true if it runs

Comment: it's just returning an empty array, getting a count of zero on it. I am basing my query off this database resource : https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Database-Description#table-woocommerce_shipping_zones

Comment: ok, but you still have to run the query in phpmyadmin to see if t returns any values, the wuery is ok, like i wrote it the second, buut you seem niot to have any data that correlates

Comment: there is data that should correlate.

Comment: look you have to providfe a {[mre] so that i can reconstruct your problem, the message **should correlate** doesn't help, when you run the query are there results or not

Comment: Managed to answer my own question. `JOIN` comes before `WHERE`. Thanks for your pointers.

Comment: there is no where clause in your query

Comment: sorry, is it then that in the `SELECT` clause you must include the table name. That was another change I made.

Comment: this is the same as i posted only you use the new prefix instead of the old prefix.and still there is **no where** clause insight